# Local Mongo DB Container Access with Kubernetes Service Endpoint in K3s is not working

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, docker, kubernetes

Earlier I used earlier kubeadm to create an endpoint from my local MongoDB which is running in a Docker container, now we have switched from kubeadm to k3s because it is a lot of easier to use. Now we are not able to use the MongoDB endpoints, it is reachable inside the Kubernetes cluster. I will share the necessary information for you. Would be glad if anybody can help me.

1. This is the Mongo DB container which is running inside usual Docker:
   [image]
2. Now I would like use it in my Kubernetes cluster, before I did a check if I am able to access inside the port 27019 and it seems to be fine.

```
user@shell:~$ curl {address-of-the-VM}:27019
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

3. Add next I created the Endpoint and service file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: dev
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 27019
    targetPort: 27019
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: dev
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: {address-of-the-VM}
    ports:
      - port: 27019
        name: mongo
```

And as next I used them for my environment variable as ConfigMap:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: spring-profile
  namespace: dev
data:
  MONGODB_HOSTS: mongo.dev
  MONGODB_PORTS: "27019"
  spring.profiles.active: dev
  stage: dev
```

And bind it to my pod in deployment:

```
    containers:
      - name: dev-server
        image: localhost:5000/dev_dev-server 
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: spring-profile
```

Now I am getting this issue, so the database can not find.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'maintenanceFeature': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'systemSrvc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemDAO': Unsatisfied dependency
```

As I mentioned earlier in our kubeadm architecture it worked very fine now it is not working.
And I checked as well if the MongoDB is in the node of K3s and yes, it is.

Comment: This IP address is the public address of the VM where MongoDB is hosted? The k3s pods by default can access the public Internet (as I tested) so it should work. Could you try [to exec into running pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) and try to run `curl mongo:27019` ? Is the  `MONGODB_HOSTS: mongo.dev` a proper one? In service you are using name `mongo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, you can use directly the IP Address `{address-of-the-VM}:27019`.